# Bootstrap Modal disappears on modifying DOM via AJAX callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap modal which has a bunch of links that trigger AJAX calls each. The user can click these links and proceed on with other work on the modal. The expectation is that the AJAX success call back will modify other DOM elements in the parent HTML document automatically.

I am able to successfully load the Modal, invoke the AJAX call and modify the underlying DOM to display the necessary information. However, as soon as the DOM is modified, the Modal disappears from screen and the screen is in a disabled state. I checked the HTML and saw that the modal is not visible but the body has the class set to `modal-open`

Not sure what my error is but your help is appreciated. Below is the code snippet showing the AJAX call when a user click on something inside the element

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function() { //this is when the user clicks on a link in the modal
            if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'linked' ) ) {
                $( this ).removeClass( 'linked' );
            } else {
                $( this ).addClass( 'linked' );
            }
            $.ajax({ 
                url: '/cake/mycontroller/link/' + $(this).parents('div#link-row').data('object-id') + '/' + objId,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    var res = $.parseJSON(response);
                    if (res.success) {
                        alert('success'); 
                        //this second ajax call is to refresh the contents of a particular DIV in the screen
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/cake/candidatesjobs/index/' + jobId,
                            type: 'ajax',
                            success: function(data) {
                                $('.links').html(data.content);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        //fail
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Have you checked what is the output of data.content using alert() after your ajax call is successfully returned? Also, I don't think changing the html of the link objects themselves is a good idea since it will disturb the bootstrap default settings. Try changing the href or onclick() attributes instead.

Comment: I just solved it - I had included the code for the Modal dialog inside the DIV with class `links` - this was getting wiped out and overwritten when I did the second AJAX call. So I moved the Modal dialog code from that DIV to the actual `body` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Solved it.

The problem was that I had the modal code within the DIV that was getting refreshed by the second AJAX call - in other words, the underlying code for Modal was getting wiped out and reloaded by the second AJAX call. To fix it, I moved the modal code from the DIV to the main `<body>` tag and the problem was solved.